# Creating custom builds of Mozilla Firefox

Tags: firefox, build, firefox-addon, mozilla

I am trying to build my own version of Firefox with slight UI changes and by adding some addons(extensions) to the build.

I have downloaded the source code from repo. Where would I start to achieve this?

Which all codes hold the UI structuring? Where do I put my addon xpi files?

PS: I tried to read the Mozilla documentation. Its either kinda outdated or I am not really getting it? A detailed insight would be much appreciated.

Comment: What is the target platform (Windows, Linux, MacOs, Other) ?

Comment: @Csaba For Linux as of now.

Comment: I think you should start with compiling the source and test if you get a running version.

Answer (score 2):

## Addons

To do this, simply place the extensions in the `distribution/extensions`
directory in the application's distribution directory.

Here are the extension
https://dxr.mozilla.org/aviary101branch/source/browser/extensions

## Flags In firefox

https://dxr.mozilla.org/aviary101branch/source/browser/config/mozconfig

## Do more with themes

https://dxr.mozilla.org/aviary101branch/source/themes/modern

https://dxr.mozilla.org/aviary101branch/source/browser/themes

## For Editing you may need XUL

https://www.xul.fr/tutorial/

## Components

Go here and customize every component you need

> https://dxr.mozilla.org/aviary101branch/source/browser/components

Comment: Should I place the extensions to `distribution/extensions` before compiling?

Comment: Hey @AnonymousPlatypus you can refer this link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Developer_guide/Customizing_Firefox for information.